# Examining a changeset in HG

Tags: git, mercurial

How can I examine a changeset in mercurial without looking up its parent?  In mercurial, what's the equivalent of

```
git show HEAD^
```

Git-show  gives the changeset metadata and the diff as well.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your question has two parts.  First, how to get the metadata and diff for a changeset all at once:

```
hg log --patch --rev tip
```

You can shorten the options:

```
hg log -pr tip
```

The second part of the question is how to say "the parent changeset of X" without looking it up.  For that you can use the [parentrevspec extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension) Martin mentioned.

Once you enable the extension you can do:

```
hg log -pr tip^
```

You could add an alias to your `~/.hgrc` file if you don't want to retrain your fingers from git's command:

```
[alias]
show = log -pr
```

Then you could use:

```
hg show tip^
```

Comment: Without parentrevspec he could just do "-r -2" to get the changeset before tip, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  That doesn't work for something like 'hg show mytag ^' though, right?

Comment: In general, for this case, `hg export` is preferred (it lists full commit message, etc.).

Comment: Preferred by who?  If you want the full commit message you can add `--verbose`/`-v` to the log command.  `log`'s output is much more human readable (the date and node/parent IDs are in a friendlier format) and it supports `--color`, unlike `export`.

Comment: `hg help revsets` is your friend.  You can use `-r 'parents(rev)'` to get all the parents (multiple in the case of merging) or `-r 'p1(rev)'` or `-r 'p2(rev)'` for the first or second parent of a rev.

Answer (score 15):

I think you want `hg export cset`.

Answer (score 5):

A similar command to "git show HEAD^" would be:

```
hg log -pr -2   # -1 (last commit), -2 - one before it, etc.
```

OR

```
hg exp tip^  # tip^ is similar to -r -2
```

or for instance if you want to look at the last 3 commits (with diff):

```
hg log -pr -3:  # colon means start 3 commits behind and up to tip inclusive
```

A bit to late with the answer, but still. :)

**UPDATE: apparently now HG supports git syntax as well:**

```
hg exp tip^^^..tip
```

or

```
hg log -pr tip~4
```

Comment: This is not an “exact equivalent”: unlike `git show`, `hg log -pr` only shows the headline of the commit message, not the entire message. To show the entire message, one must also pass `-v`, as in `hg log -pvr REV`.

Comment: @wchargin fair enough. Is the answer really bad enough for downvote? What about exp example?

Comment: I’d be more than happy to remove the downvote if the answer is fixed to not say that they are “exactly equivalent” or “equivalent” when they’re not. :-)

Comment: I had a commit whose message was originally one line long, and which I later reworded to add details. I found this answer and ran `hg log -pr -2`, and saw that the message was only one line. As this command was supposed to be *equivalent* to `git show`, it followed that I must be on the wrong commit, so I spent some time trying to find out how that might have happened. (Did I accidentally rebase/evolve something?) In reality, I was never on the wrong commit. I didn’t downvote to “nitpick”; I downvoted because the fact that this answer was incorrect caused me confusion and lost me time.

Comment: I still think it's nitpicking. I'm not even sure the `git show` was the same 6 years back. Anyway I've updated the answer to not use the word `equivalent`, to avoid any further confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see the contents and differential of a commit, use this:

```
hg diff -c <the commit hash or bookmark name>
```

To see the commit you've checked out (HEAD in git), do this:

```
hg diff -c -1
```

If you want to see the commit before it (HEAD^ in git), do this:

```
hg diff -c -2
```

Simple.

Comment: This has the benefit that it takes "--stat" like git show does.

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at the [parentrevspec extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension) to enable a more Git-like syntax for specifying revisions.