# Mercurial: diffs in a particular changeset?

Tags: mercurial

This is almost exactly a duplicate of [Examining a single changeset in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550721/examining-a-single-changeset-in-mercurial), and without doubt a duplicate of another question I can't find on SO through Google alone.

I'm looking back through a Mercurial repo, and I want to see what exactly changed between two revisions (let's say 2580 and 2581):

```
hg log -v -r 2581
```

gives me all the **files** that changed.

How can I also see the **diffs** of these files?

Thanks.

Comment: just change the `-v` to a `-p` -- see my answer below.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312633/examining-a-changeset-in-hg

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Revision 2580 isn't necessasrily the parent revision of 2581.  It's easy to check if it is, of course, but easier yet is to just do:

```
hg log -p -r 2581
```

That compares 2581 to its (first) parent revision no matter what it is, and most clearly encompasses the answer to the question *"what the hell did 2581 do?"*

Comment: You could also just use hg diff -c 2581 for that.

Comment: Wait a minute, doesn't the `-p` option mean "show patch"?

Answer (score 6):

Try `hg diff -r 2580 -r 2581`.

Answer (score 6):

```
hg diff -r 2580 -r 2581
```

This is a wrong example. The revision 2580 can be in another branch and you get diff between two branches.

Use

```
hg log -p -r 2581
```

or `hg diff -c 2581`

The difference between them in the first lines. Hg log also show information about changeset (parent, author, date, ...)

I prefer second variant `hg diff -c ...` because it can store to patch files.

`hg diff -c 2581 > revision_2581.patch`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use revset notation which IMO is a better solution as you can use it in more places consistently (ie you don't need to know about `diff -c` and `log -p` ).

```
hg diff -r 'last(ancestors(2581),2)'
```

Yes that is rather verbose compared to -c (for diff) and -p (for log).

However mercurial allows you to create revset aliases

In your `.hgrc`:

```
[revsetalias]

next(s) = descendants(s, 1)
prev(s) = last(ancestors(s),2)
```

Now you can do

```
hg diff -r 'prev(2581)'
hg log -r 'prev(2581)'
```