# Mercurial equivalent to git's HEAD~1

Tags: git, mercurial

In git it's quite convenient to identify a commit relative to the latest commit in the repo with `HEAD~1`.

I have searched and cannot find an equivalent for this in mercurial. I find mercurials revision numbers rather annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [mercurial extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension) that adds git like commands.
Specific command is  `hg log -pr .^1`.

For extra information, see [examining a changeset in hg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312633/examining-a-changeset-in-hg/1313873#1313873)

**Edit:** Use `.^1`, not `tip^1`. As mentioned below, `tip` gives the most recent commit in the entire repo, which is possibly not what you want. The `.` is closer in meaning to git's `HEAD`. (See also: [Specify dot as a revision in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180438/specify-dot-as-a-revision-in-mercurial))

Comment: These days, the relative revset syntax is supported by default. It's also useful to know that `p1()` will give the parent of the current working directory, while `tip` will give the latest commit to the whole repo (which may have been on a different branch)

Answer (score 12):

The correct answer is `.^` or `.~1`.

`tip` points to the latest revision that entered the repository, *not* the current revision you're on. Any answers that include `tip` in them are incorrect.

Mercurial's revset syntax is specified in more detail here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets

> `x^n`: The nth parent of x, n == 0, 1, or 2. For n == 0, x; for n == 1, the first parent of each changeset in x; for n == 2, the second parent of changeset in x.
>
> `x~n`: The nth first ancestor of x; "x~0" is x; "x~3" is "x^^^". For n < 0, the nth unambiguous descendant of x.
>
> `x^`: Equivalent to "x^1", the first parent of each changeset in x.

Answer (score 11):

The revset feature of Mercurial is extremely powerful (and much less arcane than git revision specification syntax): see `hg help revsets` (or online at: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#specifying-revision-sets).

See here for a list of predicates (I don't know why they aren't displayed in the online doc): http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/e597ef52a7c2/mercurial/revset.py#l811

In your case that would be: `p1(tip)`.

Comment: Since question author has better knowledge of  git syntax, I believe my answer is more useful. Still +1 since I didn't know about revsets in mercurial, and now that I've seen few examples , I prefer it to git syntax.

Comment: The link to `revset.py` seems to be broken. Could you please update it?