# Specify dot as a revision in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have found some Mercurial commands where the revision is specified as a dot; for example:

```
hg revert --all -r .
hg update -C -r .
hg pull -r .
```

What is the meaning of this dot? To which revision does it correspond?

Answer (score 6):

`hg help revisions` says:

> The reserved name "." indicates the working directory parent. If no
>   working directory is checked out, it is equivalent to null. If an
>   uncommitted merge is in progress, "." is the revision of the first
>   parent.

In most cases it will be the revision you checked out.